# Call a void in byte[]

Tags: c#

I wanted to call a void that I created, it is in byte [], but I don't know how to convert to "int" when calling it.
The command I'm showing is what I want to do, but since void is in byte [], the system says that it is impossible to convert CallInfected (byte [] infected) to int.
Remember, the void I'm trying to call is this: CallInfected (byte [] infected);

`if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2){
   this.CallInfected(0);
   playerById.Object.nameText.Color = Color.red;
}`

Cannot convert from "int" to "byte[]"

Comment: try `BitConverter.GetBytes` https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What does it mean, "void in byte[]"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call a *void method* you've created, that has an `int` parameter?  what does your `CallInfected()` method look like?  how does the `byte[]` array related to whatever the `CallInfected()` method does?  Do you mean you want to call it for *every element* in the byte array?  It's really not clear what you're asking....

Comment: So `CallInfected` only accepts a byte array? Why don't you pass a byte array then?

Comment: If `CallInfected` only accepts `byte[]`, then you can try calling it like this:  `this.CallInfected(new byte[] { 0 });

Comment: *void* is not in any way a noun in programming.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you mean to invoke `public void CallInfected(byte[] input) {...}` with an empty array which you can do like the following...

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2)) {
    //No: this.CallInfected(0);

    //Use this...
    this.CallInfected(new byte[0]);

    //or this, if it supports null input...
    this.CallInfected(null);

    playerById.Object.nameText.Color = Color.Red;
}
```